# How to access Behaviours Property attached to window from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a dependency bool property inside a behavior, which was set in Window to ask the confirmation message popup before closing window. But I don't need this popup when it is being closed from ViewModel.
So how can I access the property in the behavior and how to set it as False.

```
<Window WindowState="Normal" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        behaviors:WndExitAftConfirmBehaviour.Enabled="True"/>
```

How can I access the Enabled property in ViewModel and how to set it as False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting it to the constant `True` bind it to a boolean property in your view model and set that property to `False` when your window is closing.

If you're not using data binding then just do this instead:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.SetValue(WndExitAftConfirmBehaviour.EnabledProperty, false);
```